# What do the scifi stack exchange symbols mean?

Tags: discussion

[image]
[image]

**Do the symbols on the banner image have meaning?**

1. ?
2. some sort of cross?
3. various parts (a-j) listed below:

a. crescent moon x3

b. creepy skull x3

c. through j. look like Tolkien dwarf runes

4. some sort of angel, perhaps with only one wing.

BTW, I read the [what's meta?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page but I'm still not sure if this is a meta-type question. I apologize if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This is a question that should be on the [meta] site, as it relates to the the site itself.

Comment: @Xantec Presumably the symbols originate in some sci-fi or fantasy work and therefore are on-topic for the main site?

Comment: Also, dammit - I was planning to ask exactly this question! +1 :-)

Comment: I was totally going to ask this too, but figured it was a meta question. :')

Comment: see also: [What work of Science Fiction/ Fantasy does this Stack Exchange's symbol represent?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6390/5184) and [What is the origin/lore behind the website banner of Science Fiction & Fantasy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6415/5184)

Comment: What I've always found interesting about this symbol is that the designer had no idea that he was using a variation of the triple-Moon symbol that can represent the Wiccan belief of the Triple Goddess.